# Indefinite integral: $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-6x+18}}{x-3}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have the following indefinite at hand and I'm sure substitution is the only way I should go about solving this, but each time I think I get close, I end up at the same place, which doesn't seem to be the solution according to WolframAlpha.

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-6x+18}}{x-3}dx$$

I tried to substitute with $t=x-3$ for the denominator and a step after that $u=t^2+9$ for the numerator under the square root, but I would like to hand it over to someone who could perhaps show me a way!

Comment: After you have made this substitution, you can let $t=\tan\theta$ and $dt=\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try in the meantime, thank you

Comment: Also you can use Euler's first substitution: $$\sqrt{x^2+6x+18}=x+t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you make the standard substitution $t=3\tan\theta$, you end up needing to integrate something which apart from constants looks like $\frac{\sec^3\theta}{\tan\theta}$. What next?

There are several possibilities, none very pleasant.

One way is to rewrite the integrand as $\frac{\sec^3\theta\tan\theta}{\tan^2\theta}$, and then as $\frac{\sec^3\theta\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta-1}$. Then the substitution $w=\sec\theta$ leaves us with $\int\frac{w^2}{w^2-1}$, which is relatively easy (after division, partial fractions).

Comment: Some other options are to write $\frac{\sec^{3}\theta}{\tan\theta}$ as $\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan\theta}(\tan^{2}\theta+1)$ and simplify, or as $(\csc\theta)(\sec^{2}\theta)$ and then integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $t= \sqrt{x^2-6x+18}>3$

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-6x+18}}{x-3}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac12\int \left( 1-\frac{9}{9-t^2}\right)dt
= \frac12t-\frac32\coth^{-1}\frac t3\\
=& \ \frac12 \sqrt{x^2-6x+18}-\frac32\coth^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-6x+18}}3
\end{align}